# WPF CustomControl loses binding when collapsed

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello I made this XYController which is not binding correctly when the parent control, a `DockPanel` has its visibility set to collapsed. It is working fine when it is hidden though.

The `ThumbPosX` and `ThumbPosY` should be moving as the property `Sat` and `Val` are controlled from different places. But when it is back to Visible, they are always back at [0, 0].

```
public class XYController : Control
{
    static XYController()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(XYController), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(XYController)));
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(XYController), Thumb.DragDeltaEvent, new DragDeltaEventHandler(XYController.OnThumbDragDelta));
    }

    #region Private Members
    private const string ThumbName = "PART_Thumb";
    private TranslateTransform m_thumbTransform = new TranslateTransform();
    private Thumb m_thumb;
    #endregion


    #region Dependency Properties
    public Color SelectedColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(SelectedColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedColorProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedColorProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedColor", typeof(Color), typeof(XYController),
        new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Transparent));


    public double ThumbPosX
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ThumbPosXProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ThumbPosXProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ThumbPosXProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ThumbPosX", typeof(double), typeof(XYController),
        new PropertyMetadata(0.0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnThumbPosChanged)));


    public double ThumbPosY
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ThumbPosYProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ThumbPosYProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ThumbPosYProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ThumbPosY", typeof(double), typeof(XYController),
        new PropertyMetadata(0.0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnThumbPosChanged)));


    private static void OnThumbPosChanged(DependencyObject relatedObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        XYController xycontroller = relatedObject as XYController;
        if (xycontroller != null)
        {
            xycontroller.m_thumbTransform.X = xycontroller.ThumbPosX * xycontroller.ActualWidth;
            xycontroller.m_thumbTransform.Y = xycontroller.ThumbPosY * xycontroller.ActualHeight;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private void UpdatePosition(double positionX, double positionY)
    {
        positionX = LimitValue(positionX, ActualWidth);
        positionY = LimitValue(positionY, ActualHeight);

        m_thumbTransform.X = positionX;
        m_thumbTransform.Y = positionY;

        ThumbPosX = map(positionX, 0, ActualWidth, 0, 1);
        ThumbPosY = map(positionY, 0, ActualHeight, 0, 1);
    }

    #region Event Handlers
    private void OnThumbDragDelta(DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        double offsetX = m_thumbTransform.X + e.HorizontalChange;
        double offsetY = m_thumbTransform.Y + e.VerticalChange;
        UpdatePosition(offsetX, offsetY);
    }

    private static void OnThumbDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        XYController hsvControl = sender as XYController;
        hsvControl.OnThumbDragDelta(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_thumb != null)
        {
            Point position = e.GetPosition(this);
            UpdatePosition(position.X, ActualHeight - position.Y); //Check canvas scale in style 
            m_thumb.RaiseEvent(e);
        }
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
    {
        m_thumbTransform.X = ThumbPosX * ActualWidth;
        m_thumbTransform.Y = ThumbPosY * ActualHeight;
        base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);
    }
    #endregion

    private double LimitValue(double value, double max)
    {
        if (value < 0)
            value = 0;
        if (value > max)
            value = max;
        return value;
    }

    private double map(double value, double fromLow, double fromHigh, double toLow, double toHigh)
    {
        return (value - fromLow) * (toHigh - toLow) / (fromHigh - fromLow) + toLow;
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        m_thumb = GetTemplateChild(ThumbName) as Thumb;
        if (m_thumb != null)
        {
            UpdatePosition(this.ThumbPosX, this.ThumbPosY);
            m_thumb.RenderTransform = m_thumbTransform;
        }
    }
}
```

So I posted the whole thing because I have no idea what's missing. I have also made Custom Sliders and they are working normally when collapsed.

I use it this way :

```
    <DockPanel 
        Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=HueRadio, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}">
        <local:ColorSlider
            Minimum="0"
            Maximum="360"
            Orientation="Vertical"
            Style="{DynamicResource HueSliderVertical}"
            Value="{Binding Hue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            Margin="0, 4, 16, 4"
            />
        <local:XYController
            x:Name="HueColorControl"
            Style="{StaticResource HueController}"
            SelectedColor="{Binding SelectedColor}"
            ThumbPosX="{Binding Sat, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            ThumbPosY="{Binding Val, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            Margin="0, 4" 
            Height="200" 
            />
    </DockPanel>
```

Just a simple binding to a `RadioButton`. As said the ColorSlider which is also a `CustomControl` is moving even when the `DockPanel` is collapsed.

I tried to set the visibility directly to the XYController instead of the DockPanel but the problem remains the same.

Anything missing here ?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation of the position values involves `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` as parameters. Those values are *0* when `Visibility` is set to `Visibility.Collapsed`. `LimitValue` will always return the value of the `max` parameter (which is *0*). Also `OnThumbPosChanged` will set `m_thumbTransform` to *0*.

You must detect the collapsed state and stop calculations immediately:

```
private static void OnThumbPosChanged(DependencyObject relatedObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
    {
       return
    }

    XYController xycontroller = relatedObject as XYController;
    if (xycontroller != null)
    {
        xycontroller.m_thumbTransform.X = xycontroller.ThumbPosX * xycontroller.ActualWidth;
        xycontroller.m_thumbTransform.Y = xycontroller.ThumbPosY * xycontroller.ActualHeight;
    }
}
```

and

```
private void UpdatePosition(double positionX, double positionY)
{
    if (this.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
    {
       return;
    }

    positionX = LimitValue(positionX, ActualWidth);
    positionY = LimitValue(positionY, ActualHeight);

    m_thumbTransform.X = positionX;
    m_thumbTransform.Y = positionY;

    ThumbPosX = map(positionX, 0, ActualWidth, 0, 1);
    ThumbPosY = map(positionY, 0, ActualHeight, 0, 1);
}
```

Setting the `Visibility` back to `Visibility.Visible` would restore the last values before the collapsing. To update the position values immediately, you would need to register a `PropertyChanged` callback for the `Visibility` property:

```
static XYController()
{
    UIElement.VisibilityProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(XYController),
    new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible, OnVisibililtyChanged));


    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(XYController), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(XYController)));
    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(XYController), Thumb.DragDeltaEvent, new DragDeltaEventHandler(XYController.OnThumbDragDelta));
}

private static void OnVisibililtyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  // Update control
  OnThumbPosChanged(d, null);

  // Do more updates
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that setting the visbility to Collapsed causes a Render with ActualWidth and ActualHeight set to 0.
This would then cause your m_thumbTransform.X and m_thumbTransform.Y to be set to 0. Then when you set the Visibility back to Visible, you may not have done a render by the time ApplyTemplate occurs so ActualWidth and ActualHeight could still be 0.

I believe the issue is caused by trying to maintain the same concept (an X and Y co-ordinate pair) in 2 different places (m_thumbTransform and the Dependency Properties).

A solution would be to eliminate 1 of the 2 states so that you don't have to try to keep the information in sync and instead just have 1 source of truth.

Could you have a transform as a single dependency property and use a binding converter to set the individual components of the transform?
For example you could map Sat to X, Val to Y but also set the Scale components based on the component's Width and Height.
It might also be worth experimenting with Width, Height as well as MeasuredWidth and MeasuredHeight. As ActualWidth and ActualHeight only get set after a render cycle.